# Importer for binary datafile of PI88 Nanoindenter

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, numpy

As an exercise, I want to rewrite a C++ program to import measurement files (and later create excelsheets, reports ...). The measurement files split in 2 files, a binary file, and a xml-file. Because I can't control how the vendor might change the file structure or the names for data, I thought up a way, to put them as a list of tuples (attribute name for python, data name as in the xml-file) at the beginning of my classes, and use this list to create parameters/access data. IMHO that should make it easier in the future to adjust for changes with the measurement file format. Is this a good idea? Or are there potential issues down the road, I'm not aware of? (one problem I already encountered: pycharms code completition is not working when using setattrib - but thats not a huge issue for me). Also feedback for the rest of the code is welcome.

Code on github: https://github.com/natter1/pi88reader

There you can also find example measurement files:

https://github.com/natter1/pi88reader/tree/master/resources

pi88importer.py:

```
import pi88reader.tdm_importer as tdm
import numpy as np


def main():
    """
    Called at end of file, if __name__ == "__main__"
    """
    measurement = PI88Measurement('..\\resources\\quasi_static_12000uN.tdm')
    # measurement = PI88Measurement('..\\resources\\nan_error_dyn_10000uN.tdm')

    print(measurement.settings.dict)
    print(measurement.area_function.b)
    for name_tuple in PI88Measurement.static_name_tuples:
        print(name_tuple[0], getattr(measurement, name_tuple[0]))
    for name_tuple in PI88Segments.name_tuples:
        print(name_tuple[0], getattr(measurement.segments, name_tuple[0]))
    for name_tuple in PI88Measurement.dynamic_name_tuples:
        print(name_tuple[0], getattr(measurement, name_tuple[0]))


class PI88AreaFunction:
    data_names = [
        ("filename", "Acquisition_Area_Function_Name"),
        ("b", "Current_Area_Function_B"),
        ("c0", "Current_Area_Function_C0"),
        ("c1", "Current_Area_Function_C1"),
        ("c2", "Current_Area_Function_C2"),
        ("c3", "Current_Area_Function_C3"),
        ("c4", "Current_Area_Function_C4"),
        ("c5", "Current_Area_Function_C5")
    ]

    def __init__(self, settings_dict={}):
        # only needed, to make pycharm code completion work:
        self.b = None
        self.c0 = None
        # ...
        self.read(settings_dict)

    def read(self, settings):
        """
        Read area function parameters from a dictionary (settings).
        :param settings: dict
        :return: None
        """
        for data_name in PI88AreaFunction.data_names:
            if data_name[1] in settings:
                setattr(self, data_name[0], settings[data_name[1]])
            else:
                setattr(self, data_name[0], None)

    def get_area(self, h):
        return (self.c0 * h**2
                + self.c1 * h
                + self.c2 * h**(1/2)
                + self.c3 * h**(1/4)
                + self.c4 * h**(1/8)
                + self.c5 * h**(1/16)
                )


class PI88Segments:
    # (attribute_name, TDM-channelname)
    name_tuples = [
        ("timestamp_begin", "Segment Begin Time"),
        ("timestamp_end", "Segment End Time"),
        ("time", "Segment Time"),
        ("begin_demand", "Segment Begin Demand"),
        ("end_demand", "Segment End Demand"),

        ("fb_mode", "Segment FB Mode"),
        ("points", "Segment Points"),
        ("lia_status", "Segment LIA Status")
    ]

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.points_compressed = None
        self._read(data)

    def _read(self, data):
        group_name = "Segments"
        data._read_from_channel_group(group_name, PI88Segments.name_tuples, self)
        print(data.get_channel_dict(group_name))


class PI88Settings:
    # self.settings dictonary names for important settings
    important_settings_names = [
        "Current_Machine_Compliance__nm___mN__",
        "Current_Tip_Modulus__MPa__",
        "Current_Tip_Poissons_Ratio",
        "Acquisition_Tare",
        "Acquisition_Transducer_Type",
        "Acquisition_Test_Aborted",
        "Current_Drift_Correction",
        "Current_Drift_Rate__nm___s__"
    ]

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.dict = {}
        self._read(data)

    def _read(self, data):
        self.dict = data.get_instance_attributes_dict()


class PI88Measurement:
    # (attribute_name, TDM-channelname)
    static_name_tuples = [
        ("time", "Test Time"),
        ("depth", "Indent Disp."),
        ("load", "Indent Load"),
        ("load_actual", "Indent Act. Load"),
        ("depth_v", "Indent Disp. Volt."),
        ("load_v", "Indent Act. Load Volt."),
        ("output_v", "Indent Act. Output Volt.")
    ]
    # (attribute_name, TDM-channelname)
    dynamic_name_tuples = [
        # channel groupname: Indentation Averaged Values
        ("average_dynamic_time", "Test Time"),
        ("average_dynamic_depth", "Indent Disp."),
        ("average_dynamic_load", "Indent Load"),
        ("average_dynamic_load_actual", "Indent Act. Load"),
        ("average_dynamic_depth_v", "Indent Disp. Volt."),
        ("average_dynamic_load_v", "Indent Act. Load Volt."),
        ("average_dynamic_output_v", "Indent Act. Output Volt."),

        # channel groupname: "Basic Dynamic Averaged Values 1"
        ("average_dynamic_freq", "Dynamic Freq."),
        ("average_dynamic_disp_amp", "Disp. Amp."),
        ("average_dynamic_phase_shift", "Phase Shift"),
        ("average_dynamic_load_amp", "Load Amp."),
        ("average_dynamic_dyn_comp", "Dynamic Comp."),
        ("average_dynamic_disp_amp_v", "Disp. Amp. Volt."),
        ("average_dynamic_load_amp_v", "Load Amp. Volt."),

        # channel groupname: "Visco-Elastic: Indentation Averaged Values 1"
        ("average_dynamic_storage_mod", "Storage Mod."),
        ("average_dynamic_loss_mod", "Loss Mod."),
        ("average_dynamic_tan_delta", "Tan-Delta"),
        ("average_dynamic_complex_mod", "Complex Mod."),
        ("average_dynamic_hardness", "Hardness"),
        ("average_dynamic_contact_area", "Contact Area"),
        ("average_dynamic_contact_depth", "Contact Depth")
    ]

    def __init__(self, filename):
        # todo: how to make it work with 'with' statement
        data = tdm.TdmData(filename)

        self.segments = PI88Segments(data)
        self.settings = PI88Settings(data)
        self.area_function = PI88AreaFunction(self.settings.dict)
        self._read_quasi_static(data)
        self._read_average_dynamic(data)

        for name_tuple in PI88Measurement.dynamic_name_tuples:
            self.remove_nans(name_tuple[0])

    def _read_quasi_static(self, data):
        group_name = "Indentation All Data Points"
        data._read_from_channel_group(group_name, PI88Measurement.static_name_tuples, self)
        # print(data.channel_dict(group_name))

    def _read_average_dynamic(self, data):
        group_name = "Indentation Averaged Values"
        data._read_from_channel_group(group_name, PI88Measurement.dynamic_name_tuples[0:7], self)
        # print(data.channel_dict(group_name))

        group_name = "Basic Dynamic Averaged Values 1"
        data._read_from_channel_group(group_name, PI88Measurement.dynamic_name_tuples[7:14], self)

        group_name = "Visco-Elastic: Indentation Averaged Values 1"
        data._read_from_channel_group(group_name, PI88Measurement.dynamic_name_tuples[14:], self)

    def remove_nans(self, attribute_name):
        """
        Sometimes it happens in dynamic mode, that measurement values are invalid (-> nan).
        Those invalid values can be removed with this method.

        :param attribute_name: Name (self.attribute_name) to be cleaned.
        :return: None
        """
        array = getattr(self, attribute_name, None)
        if array is not None:
            mask = np.invert(np.isnan(array))
            setattr(self, attribute_name, array[mask])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

tdm_importer.py

```
"""This module allows National Instruments TDM/TDX files to be accessed like
NumPy structured arrays.

==============================================================================
Inspired by the module tdm-loader (https://pypi.org/project/tdm-loader/):
from Josh Ayers and Florian Dobener
==============================================================================
"""
import os.path
import re
import warnings
import xml.etree.ElementTree

import numpy as np

# dictionary for converting from NI to NumPy datatypes
DTYPE_CONVERTERS = {'eInt8Usi': 'i1',
                    'eInt16Usi': 'i2',
                    'eInt32Usi': 'i4',
                    'eInt64Usi': 'i8',
                    'eUInt8Usi': 'u1',
                    'eUInt16Usi': 'u2',
                    'eUInt32Usi': 'u4',
                    'eUInt64Usi': 'u8',
                    'eFloat32Usi': 'f4',
                    'eFloat64Usi': 'f8',
                    'eStringUsi': 'U'}


def get_usi_from_string(string):
    if string is None or string.strip() == '':
        return []
    else:
        return re.findall("id\(\"(.+?)\"\)", string)


class TdmChannel:
    def __init__(self, root, _id):
        self.xml_root = root
        self.id = _id
        self.name = None
        self.description = None
        self.unit = None
        self.inc = None
        self.data_type = None
        self.local_columns_usi = None

        self.read()

    def read(self):
        element = self.xml_root.find(f'.//tdm_channel[@id=\'{self.id}\']')
        self.name = element.find("name").text
        self.description = element.find("description").text
        self.unit = element.find("unit_string").text
        self.data_type = element.find("datatype").text
        self.local_columns_usi = get_usi_from_string(element.findtext('local_columns'))[0]
        self.inc = self._get_inc()

    def _get_data_usi(self, root):
        local_column = root.find(
            f".//localcolumn[@id='{self.local_columns_usi}']")
        return get_usi_from_string(local_column.findtext('values'))[0]

    def _get_inc(self):
        data_type = self.data_type.split('_')[1].lower() + '_sequence'
        data_usi = self._get_data_usi(self.xml_root)
        return self.xml_root.find(
            f".//{data_type}[@id='{data_usi}']/values").get('external')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"TdmChannel object\n" \
               f"\tid: {self.id}\n" \
               f"\tName: {self.name}\n" \
               f"\tDescription: {self.description}\n" \
               f"\tUnit: {self.unit}\n" \
               f"\tdata type: {self.data_type}" \
               f"\tinc: {self.inc}"


class TdmChannelGroup:
    def __init__(self, root, id):
        self.id = None
        self.name = None
        self.description = None
        self.channel_ids = []
        self.channels = []

        self.read(root, id)
        self.read_channels(root)

    def read(self, root, _id):
        element = root.find(f'.//tdm_channelgroup[@id=\'{_id}\']')
        self.id = element.get('id')
        self.name = element.find("name").text
        self.description = element.find("description").text
        self.channel_ids = get_usi_from_string(element.findtext('channels'))

    def read_channels(self, root):
        for channel_id in self.channel_ids:
            self.channels.append(TdmChannel(root, channel_id))

    #        print(self.channels[0])

    def get_channel(self, channel_name):
        result = [x for x in self.channels if x.name == channel_name]
        if len(result) == 0:
            return None
        return result[0]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"TdmChannelGroup object\n" \
               f"\tid: {self.id}\n" \
               f"\tName: {self.name}\n" \
               f"\tDescription: {self.description}\n" \
               f"\tChannel ids: {self.channel_ids.__str__()}"


class TdmData:
    """Class for importing data from National Instruments TDM/TDX files."""

    def __init__(self, tdm_file):
        """
        :param tdm_file: str
            The filename including full path to the .TDM xml-file.
        """
        self._folder, self._tdm_filename = os.path.split(tdm_file)
        self.root = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(tdm_file).getroot()
        self._tdx_order = 'C'  # Set binary file reading to column-major style
        self._tdx_filename = self.root.find('.//file').get('url')
        self._tdx_path = os.path.join(self._folder, self._tdx_filename)

        self.channel_groups = []
        self.read_channel_groups()

    def read_channel_groups(self):
        ids = get_usi_from_string(self.root.findtext('.//tdm_root//channelgroups'))
        for _id in ids:
            self.channel_groups.append(TdmChannelGroup(self.root, _id))

    def get_channel_group_names(self):
        """
        Returns a list with all channel_group names.
        :return: list of str
        """
        return [x.name for x in self.channel_groups
                if x.name is not None]

    def get_channel_names(self, channel_group_name):
        """
        Returns a list with all channel names in channel_group.
        :param channel_group_name: str
        :return: list of str
        """
        channels = self.get_channel_group(channel_group_name).channels
        return [channel.name for channel in channels
                if channel.name is not None]

    def get_channel_dict(self, channel_group_name):
        """Returns a dict with {channel: data} entries of a channel_group.

        :param channel_group_name: str
        :return: dict
        """
        channel_dict = {}
        name_doublets = set()

        for channel_name in self.get_channel_names(channel_group_name):
            if channel_name in channel_dict:
                name_doublets.add(channel_name)
            inc = self.get_channel(channel_group_name, channel_name).inc
            data = self._get_data(inc)
            channel_dict[channel_name] = np.array(data)

        if len(name_doublets) > 0:
            warnings.warn(f"Duplicate channel name(s): {name_doublets}")
        return channel_dict

    def get_channel_group(self, group_name):
        result = [x for x in self.channel_groups if x.name == group_name]
        if len(result) == 0:
            return None
        return result[0]

    def get_channel(self, channel_group_name, channel_name):
        channel_group = self.get_channel_group(channel_group_name)
        if channel_group:
            return channel_group.get_channel(channel_name)
        return None

    def get_endian_format(self):
        """
        Returns '<' for littleEndian and '>' for bigEndian
        :return: '<' or '>'
        """
        order = self.root.find('.//file').get('byteOrder')
        if order == 'littleEndian':
            return '<'
        elif order == 'bigEndian':
            return '>'
        else:
            raise TypeError('Unknown endian format in TDM file')

    def _get_dtype_from_tdm_type(self, value_type):
        return np.dtype(self.get_endian_format() + DTYPE_CONVERTERS[value_type])

    def _get_data(self, inc):
        """Gets data binary tdx-file belonging to the given inc.

        :param inc: int
        :return: numpy data or None
            Returns None, if inc is None, else returns numpy data.
        """
        if inc is None:
            return None
        else:
            ext_attribs = self.root.find(f".//file/block[@id='{inc}']").attrib
            return np.memmap(
                self._tdx_path,
                offset=int(ext_attribs['byteOffset']),
                shape=(int(ext_attribs['length']),),
                dtype=self._get_dtype_from_tdm_type(ext_attribs['valueType']),
                mode='r',
                order=self._tdx_order
            ).view(np.recarray)

    def _read_data(self, channel, attribute_name, to_object):
        if channel:
            setattr(to_object, attribute_name, self._get_data(channel.inc))
        else:
            setattr(to_object, attribute_name, None)

    def _read_from_channel_group(self, group_name, name_tuples, to_object):
        """
        Read channels data (names given in name_tuples) from group_name into
        to_object, by setting the attribute names given via name_tuples.
        If some data wasn't found, the attribute is set to None.
        :param group_name: str
        :param name_tuples: (str, str)
            (attribute_name, channel_name)
        :param to_object: object
        :return: None
        """
        for name_tuple in name_tuples:
            channel = self.get_channel(group_name, name_tuple[1])
            self._read_data(channel, name_tuple[0], to_object)

    def get_instance_attributes_dict(self):
        """
        Function specific for PI88 measurement files
        :return: dict
        """

        def get_name_value_pair(element):
            if element.tag == 'string_attribute':
                return {element.get("name"): element.find("s").text}
            elif element.tag == 'double_attribute':
                return {element.get("name"): float(element.text)}
            elif element.tag == 'long_attribute':
                return {element.get("name"): int(element.text)}
            # todo: 'time_attribute'
            else:
                return {element.get("name"): element.text}

        result = {}
        element = self.root.find(".//tdm_root//instance_attributes")
        for child in element:
            result.update(get_name_value_pair(child))

        return result
```